# How to extract the entire row and columns when condition met in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array in this form:

```
array([['A', 2.2, 9.1],
   ['A', 7.1, 2.3],
   ['B', 4.1, 1.1]],dtype=object)
```

So I would like to query 'A' and then return all rows and columns with (matching) the string 'A'. Anything not matching the condition is ignored. So the output should be:

```
form = array([['A', 2.2, 9.1],
              ['A', 7.1, 2.3],dtype=object)
```

I tried using `j = form[np.where(form == 'A')]`

which gives `array(['A', 'A'], dtype=object)`. This is not what I want.

Could someone please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Storing different `dtypes` in a numpy array is NOT a good idea! A good tool to do things like this would be `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the array when using `np.where()` so that only this first column is used:

```
form = np.array([['A', 2.2, 9.1],
   ['A', 7.1, 2.3],
   ['B', 4.1, 1.1]],dtype=object)

j = form[np.where(form[:,0]=='A')]
print (j)
# [['A' 2.2 9.1]
#  ['A' 7.1 2.3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `where` like so:

```
form = np.array([['A', 2.2, 9.1],
             ['A', 7.1, 2.3],
             ['B', 4.1, 1.1]])

print(form[form[:,0] == 'A'])

# [['A' 2.2 9.1] 
#  ['A' 7.1 2.3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list comprehension then in it we iterate trough the length of `test` then check if `'A'` is in the list witch is the element with the index of `i`:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([['A', 2.2, 9.1],
   ['A', 7.1, 2.3],
   ['B', 4.1, 1.1]],dtype=object)
print(test[[i for i in range(len(test)) if 'A' in test[i]]])
```

Output:

```
[['A' 2.2 9.1]
 ['A' 7.1 2.3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way:

```
import numpy as np
form = np.array([row for row in form_original if row[0] == "A"])
```